# Why can't i define variable in some conditional expressions in php

Tags: php, variables

I have seen that

`isset($n=$this->myvariable)` does not work

but this works

`array_key_exists($t=$this->type, $m=$this->map)`

also

`if($n=$this->myvariable)` also does not work

Comment: What is `%this->myvariable`? Is it set? The last one should work.

Comment: "Why" questions are the domain of the language developers. We can describe what works and what doesn't, but any response to the "why" question will mostly be guesswork.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins i want to know how can i describe variable inside `isset` because sometimes i need to use that in next statement and i don't want to write long text again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`isset`  is specifically intended to determine if a reference to a variable, array index, or object property has be set.  It needs to be passed in one of those.   `$n = $this->myvariable` actuall evaluates to a value being assigned to `$n` and not the variable `$n` itself.

`if` is a language construct, not a function/method.  It determine if whatever is inside it evaluates to `true` or `false`.  This can be a variable or a conditional or a function call or the result of an asisgnment to name a few

array_key_exists() takes 2 arguments: the first is just about anything, the second is an array.  These can be passed in explicitly by value or by their variable.  For example:

```
  array_key_exists('123', array());
```

is perfectly fine, even though no variables are being created or passed in.

This is differnt with isset() as these all would error:

```
  isset(array()); 
  isset(1);
  isset('somestring');
```

as no variable is being passed in..

For once in my life, I can honestly say something like this would be easier to explain in JAVA and C where the concept of pointers and references are clearer and more prevalent :)